# compile ffmpeg to enable libmp3lame

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, libraries

I  am using the following command in MinGW in windows to build my ffmpeg, I have already downloaded libmp3lame from here [sourceforge.net](http://lame.sourceforge.net/developers.php) compiled the build and compile and install the libmp3lame, now I see the lame.exe file and can use the command line lame to convert a file to mp3, but when I try to configure my ffmpeg as I said before like:

configure --prefix=ffmpeg/ --disable-network --disable-debug --enable-libmp3l
me --enable-gpl

```
ERROR: libmp3lame >= 3.98.3 not found

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solving the problem.
```

the libmp3lame I am using is lame 3.98.4 so it does meet the conditions and the command statement was throwing that same error even before I install libmp3lame, so its obviously is not recognizing that its there, could someone help me